# mysql calculation of balance grouped by date

Tags: mysql

So let me describe what i would like to calculate here. I have 2 tables , on the first table which is called balance i have one row for each account and its corresponding current balance.On the second table i have all the deposits and withdrawals for those accounts and the exact date time when those deposits and withdrawals took place. My problem is to calculate , based on those 2 tables , the balance of all the accounts for each day.

1.table balance

```
|account_id| balance |
|1111      |   1000  |
|2222      |   3500  |
|3333      |   10000 |
```

2.table credit

```
account_id|         date      |deposit_withdrawal|
|1111     |2012-11-11 12:35:02|        250       |
|1111     |2012-11-12 18:15:34|        750       |
|1111     |2012-11-12 09:09:04|       -150       |
|2222     |2012-01-12 10:05:04|       1000       |
|2222     |2012-07-15 14:23:04|        -340      |
|2222     |2012-12-29 13:01:04|        450       |
```

I select the accounts from the credit table , get the sum of their deposit_withdrawal and then group it by the DAYOFYEAR.Now i'm stuck , i cant figure out how to calculate their balance on each of those dates. As i mentioned above , the balance table contains the current balance of the accounts. So the most recent entry on the deposit_withdrawal table is already accounted in the balance table.

```
SELECT c.account_id , c.date , SUM(c.deposit_withdrawal)  FROM credit c
JOIN balance b  on b.account_id = c.account_id
GROUP by DAYOFYEAR (c.date)
ORDER BY DAYOFYEAR(c.date) DESC
```

EDIT : Thank you all for your replies and let me explain this a bit more , lets say we have  an account with current balance of 2000. In the table credit he has 3 entries ,1 on 2012-10-10 with withdrawal of 300 ,  1 on 2012-11-11 with deposit of 400 and the last one and the most recent one on 2013-02-29 with deposit of 150. The thing i want to do is to find his balance for all the dates between 2013-02-29 and 2012-10-09. I know that on 2013-02-29 which is the most recent one his balance is equal to his  current balance = 2000. So the day before , on 2013-02-28 i know that his balance would be current balance(2000) - last deposit (150) = 1850. Up until 2012-11-11 his balance didn't change.On 2012-11-11 he had deposited 400 , so the day before on 2012-11-10 his balance would be 1850-400 = 1450 and so on.

Comment: Why do you have to JOIN the two? balance per day is not going to be equal to total balance

Comment: *"the balance of all the accounts for each day"* The solution to that problem is `SELECT SUM(balance) FROM balance`, so I suppose you're not asking your question correctly. I have no clue what your intended end result is.

Comment: I've edited the post and included an update.Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably be storing the balance in the credit table when you add a new record, it would make things simpler. But - we can solve this without the historical info, we just need to build some kind of transaction history.

We can do this by looking at each credit record, finding the records which come after it and applying them to the balance:

```
CREATE TABLE transaction_history (
SELECT
    credit.account_id,
    credit.`date`,
    credit.deposit_withdrawal,
    COALESCE(balance.balance - SUM(next_transactions.deposit_withdrawal), balance.balance) AS balance
FROM
    credit
LEFT JOIN
    credit AS next_transactions
ON
    next_transactions.account_id = credit.account_id
AND
    next_transactions.`date` > credit.`date`
INNER JOIN
    balance
ON
    balance.account_id = credit.account_id
GROUP BY
    credit.account_id,
    credit.`date`,
    credit.deposit_withdrawal
ORDER BY
    credit.`date` DESC
);
```

This generates us the balance for each account for each credit record. But to use this properly, we need to take into account the starting balances of the accounts:

```
INSERT INTO transaction_history (account_id, `date`, deposit_withdrawal, balance) (
SELECT
    balance.account_id,
    '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    0,
    COALESCE(earliest_transaction.balance - earliest_transaction.deposit_withdrawal, balance.balance) AS `balance`
FROM
    balance
LEFT JOIN
    transaction_history AS earliest_transaction
ON
    earliest_transaction.account_id = balance.account_id
AND
    earliest_transaction.`date` = (SELECT MIN(`date`) FROM transaction_history AS te WHERE te.account_id = balance.account_id)
);
```

This inserts records for time 0 as the balance before any of the other transactions are applied, so account 1111 has 150, account 2222 has 2390 and account 3333 has 10000. You should end up with data which looks like this:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM transaction_history;
+------------+---------------------+--------------------+---------+
| account_id | date                | deposit_withdrawal | balance |
+------------+---------------------+--------------------+---------+
|       2222 | 2012-12-29 13:01:04 |                450 |    3500 |
|       1111 | 2012-11-12 18:15:34 |                750 |    1000 |
|       1111 | 2012-11-12 09:09:04 |               -150 |     250 |
|       1111 | 2012-11-11 12:35:02 |                250 |     400 |
|       2222 | 2012-07-15 14:23:04 |               -340 |    3050 |
|       2222 | 2012-01-12 10:05:04 |               1000 |    3390 |
|       1111 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                  0 |     150 |
|       2222 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                  0 |    2390 |
|       3333 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                  0 |   10000 |
+------------+---------------------+--------------------+---------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then, if you want to find the balance for a given account at the end of a specific day, you can use this query:

```
SELECT 
    balance 
FROM 
    transaction_history 
WHERE 
    account_id = 1111 
AND 
    `date` <= '2012-11-12 23:59:59'  
ORDER BY 
    `date` DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!  i think that'll solve my problem.